# Where does the LOCAL SYSTEM account store its "personal" files?

Tags: windows-server-2008, local-system

I'm using a continous integration system (CruiseControl.NET) as a service on our Windows 2008 64-bit server.

Now I would like to run Delphi 2006 from CruiseControl.NET (which runs as a service).

The point where I'm stuck is that Delphi 2006 requires a folder with licensing information in the users home folder. It won't run if it can't find the licensing information.

Where is that folder for the `LOCAL SYSTEM` account? I've looked in `C:\Users` but no luck.

I could also run the service using the `LOCAL SERVICE` account but there is no folder for that account either under `C:\Users\`.

Comment: Or see http://serverfault.com/questions/9325/where-can-i-find-data-stored-by-a-windows-service-running-as-local-system-accoun

Answer (score 40):

The "user profile" of the LocalSystem account is stored in `C:\Windows\System32\Config\systemprofile`.

---

### Edit:

Seen your edit to the main post; just a comment: it would be a lot better to use a service account for your application instead of LocalSystem.

Answer (score 1):

The Local System Account is not the same as a regular user account (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684190%28VS.85%29.aspx) for the full lowdown).

In your situation you could...

1. Create a dedicated account for it (not strictly necessary, but best practice).
2. Give the account the permissions it needs to function.
3. Go to services.msc find the service in question open it and set it to log on as the user account you created.

Comment: The LocalSystem account actually **has** a user profile; see my answer. Agreed that you shouldn't need to ever modify it, but it's there anyway.