# Retrieve Windows services information from previous Windows installation

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-service

We have a client whose server crashed, and they reinstalled Windows (2003 R2). They have kept the old Windows folder as Windows1.

Now we have to recreate some of the Windows Services that were on the old setup, but I have no idea which programs and params it had.

Are there any way that I can still retrieve the old Services from the Windows1 folder?

Comment: This operating system is **well** past EOL. Continuing to use it is irresponsible.

Comment: Presuming that your fresh install has the default services running, have you tried to figure out if anything is missing?  (I also presume that software needed to be installed which might have installed their own services already).  If no functions are missing then perhaps the issue is moot.

Comment: Yes, the default services are running, and there were 2 services created by another vendor that are now missing. If I can view the details of the old services, then I might be able to find the files and recreate the services.

Comment: Can't "they" help tell you which services had been running? Or maybe they could indicate what stopped working when the server crashed. It seems easier than to make guesses, and depending on what caused the server to crash in the first place, you might end up restoring something that causes the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System registry hive from the old server if the files still exist in the Windows1 folder. You can then compare that hive to the new server and see what services are missing on the new server.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724877(v=vs.85).aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732157(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Thanks for constructively answering the question that was asked.  I will test it out and mark as answer if it works.

Comment: Any idea where these files in the Windows1 folder might be stored? I had a look at the locations specified here, but it's empty: https://serverfault.com/questions/9325/where-can-i-find-data-stored-by-a-windows-service-running-as-local-system-accou

Comment: The files should be in the Windows1\System32\Config folder.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's no way for you to know what it was in the previous box. 
Just help them to migrate to a newer and or use windows xp mode or a VM to help them.

Comment: The same problem will still exist. I still need to create services that I do not know what and where.